# Are there any differences between "I put the clothes on" and "I put on the clothes"?

Tags: meaning

I want to know the difference between "I put the clothes on" and "I put on the clothes".
Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: No difference in meaning.

Comment: @BillFranke Forgive me if I'm wrong, but couldn't "I put the clothes on" have a different meaning, depending on context? For instance, couldn't it mean "I put the clothes on _the line_" or something?

Comment: @Mr Lister: Yes, but those are two different sentences because you've added _the line_, which changes the verb from the phrasal verb _put on_ to the the normal verb _put_ plus the prepositional phrase _on the line_. If you've got "There were new clothes on the bed. I put on the clothes." and "There were new clothes on the bed. I put the clothes on.", there's no difference in meaning.

Comment: So long as the end state is the same (i.e., you're wearing the clothes), there's no difference in meaning.

Comment: If "the clothes" is replaced by some long phrase, then "on" just after "put" may be clearer than "on" far away.  Ralphie put the ugly bunny suit his grandmother had given him on.

Answer (score 1):

*Put on* is a phrasal verb, and transitive phrasal verbs such as this allow movement of the particle, *on* in this case, when the object is not a pronoun. If the sentences describe the act of dressing, then the meaning is the same.

There may, however, be a difference between British and American English in the choice between the two. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 23 records for ‘put on my clothes’, but only 9 for ‘put my clothes on’. The British National Corpus has one record for each. These results are not necessarily conclusive, particularly given the virtually insignificant returns from the BNC, but they suggest a tendency which might merit further investigation.